# C# extend method for Enum object

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an extension method but can't get it to work.

So this works, create extension method on a Type of enum example:

```
public enum Pets
{
    ....
}
```

Above Pets can be extended creating an extension method like:

```
public static void Myex(this Pets pet)
{
    ... 
}
```

But when I try to extend Enum itself example below:

```
Public static void something(this Enum en)
{
    ... 
}
```

And try to use it like below

```
Enum.something();
```

this doesn't work.

I was trying to create similar method like Enum.Parse, Enum.IsDefined (which are already exposed by c#).

Comment: Obviously `Enum` has no `Something`

Comment: You have to create an instance of `Enum` to call the method on, not call it like a static method on the `Enum` class.

Comment: I'm curious what really are you planning to have in that method?

Comment: @IvanStoev I was trying to create a method like Parse ( which is already exposed by c#). Although looking at below answers it doesn't look like it's possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Enum` as such - but extension methods "look" like they're *instance* methods. You can't "pretend" to add static methods, as it looks like you're currently trying to do.

You would be able to do:

```
Pets.SomeValue.something()
```

... because that's calling the extension method on an "instance" (a value). It will end up boxing the value, mind you.

Comment: Why would this result in boxing?

Comment: @roryap: Because `Enum` is a reference type.

Comment: Is there some way to modify the code to avoid boxing?  Or is that always the case with extension methods on enum types?  Where in the code is the boxing (wrapping the value in an `Object`) happening?

Comment: I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691158%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which indicates boxing occurs when converting "From any enum-type to the type System.Enum.", but the OP isn't converting to `System.Enum` anywhere, right?

Comment: @roryap: The boxing would happen at the call site. It's nothing to do with extension methods... if you just called it using `SomeClassName.Foo(Pets.SomeValue)` you'd get the exact same effect.

Comment: @roryap: Yes, they are, because they've got an extension method with an `Enum` parameter.

Comment: Oh okay, my mistake.  I thought your answer was calling `Myex` when in fact it's calling `something`.  I see it now.

Answer (score 3):

Enum is a type name. You should use extension methods for instance. Next code works fine:

```
public static class A
{
    public static void DoWork(this Enum en)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(en);
    }

    public static void DoWork(this int en)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(en);
    }
}

public enum Pets
{
    Cat,
    Dog
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cat = Pets.Cat;
        //Enum.DoWork(); doesn't work
        cat.DoWork(); // works fine
        //int.DoWork(); doesn't work
        5.DoWork(); // works fine
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Extension methods**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) are really powerful and fun.  In order to correctly create an extension method you need to have a non-nested static class that then exposes a static method.  The static method's first parameter must include the this keyword of the type that you're extending.  For example if you want to extend the `Pets enum` specifically, then you need to have an extension whose extension method correctly specifies the parameter, likewise for targeting `Enum`.  See below:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Grizzlies live in water = " + Pets.NorthAmericanGrizzly.LivesInWater());
        Console.WriteLine("Fish live in water = " + Pets.Fish.LivesInWater());
        Console.WriteLine("Cat is a pet enum = " + Pets.Cat.IsPetEnum());
        Console.WriteLine("Date Time Kind of UTC is a pet enum = " + DateTimeKind.Utc.IsPetEnum());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public enum Pets
{
    Dog,
    Cat,
    Fish,
    Shark,
    NorthAmericanGrizzly
}

public static class PetExtensions
{
    public static bool LivesInWater(this Pets pet)
    {
        return pet == Pets.Fish || pet == Pets.Shark;
    }
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static bool IsPetEnum(this Enum @enum)
    {
        return @enum is Pets;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Grizzlies live in water = False
Fish live in water = True
Cat is a pet enum = True
Date Time Kind of UTC is a pet enum = False
```